# Adding Activated events for ComponentRegistrations which have been AutoActivated

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

I'm trying to attach an `Activated` event handler to `Components` which implement a specific interface.

I want to do this in one place globally, and not have to call a method for each registration. i.e. OnActivated isn't suitable, as it's a per-registration call.

To do that I have a `RegisterBuildCallback` which loops over the `ComponentRegistry.Registrations` attaching to the `Activated` event where appropriate.

The problem I've found is that `Components` marked as `AutoActivate` are activated before the `RegisterBuildCallback` is run. So `Activated` isn't called for `AutoActivate` `Components`, or rather is called before I have attached the event handler.

`AutoActivate` is working as intended, and as described by the documentation:

> An auto-activated component is a component that simply needs to be activated one time **when the container is built**.

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html#auto-activated-components

Here's an MCVE:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using Autofac;

namespace AutofacActivatedNotCalled
{
    public interface ISomething { }
    public interface IFoo { }
    public interface IBar { }
    public class Foo : IFoo, ISomething { }
    public class Bar : IBar, ISomething { }
    public class Baz { public Baz(IFoo foo) { } }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Add callback which hooks up Activated event.
            builder
                .RegisterBuildCallback(builtContainer =>
                {
                    var iSomethingRegistrations = builtContainer
                        .ComponentRegistry
                        .Registrations
                        .Where(registration => IsISomething(registration.Activator.LimitType))
                        .ToList();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Found {iSomethingRegistrations.Count} ISomething Registrations");

                    foreach (var iSomethingRegistration in iSomethingRegistrations)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"ISomething {iSomethingRegistration.Activator.LimitType.Name} Add Activated");

                        iSomethingRegistration.Activated += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"ISomething {eventArgs.Instance.GetType().Name} Activated");
                        };
                    }
                });

            // Register services
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().SingleInstance();

            builder
                .RegisterType<Bar>()
                .As<IBar>()
                .SingleInstance()
                .AutoActivate()
                .OnActivated(eventArgs => Console.WriteLine($"IBar Activated"));

            builder.RegisterType<Baz>();

            // Build container
            var container = builder.Build();

            // Resolve service
            var baz = container.Resolve<Baz>();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool IsISomething(Type type)
            => (type == typeof(ISomething))
            || type.GetInterfaces().Any(interfaceType => interfaceType == typeof(ISomething));
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
    IBar Activated
    Found 2 ISomething Registrations
    ISomething Foo Add Activated
    ISomething Bar Add Activated
    ISomething Foo Activated
```

As mentioned, I'm trying to avoid using `OnActivated` when registering the `Component`. It's included in the example to show that `Activate` is being fired, but before the `RegisterBuildCallback` is run.

Is there a way to handle `AutoActivated` `Components` with my approach?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to do something on activation for every Component that implements a specific interface. The specific use is to subscribe to a message bus using the method exposed by the interface.

Comment: I've removed the last bit of text for clarity, to make sure I'm only asking one question at a time.

Comment: I can not see any issue except that you have used both `OnActivated` and `Activated`.

Comment: The issue is that `AutoActivate` components are activated before `RegisterBuildCallback` is called. So `Activated` isn't called for `AutoActivate` components, because they were activated before `RegisterBuildCallback` was called. Hence _"Is there a way to handle AutoActivated Components with my approach?"_.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit to indicate the preference for `Activated` and not `OnActivated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoActivate` are getting activated immediately on calling `Build` method. You don't even need the `Activated` event to catch them.

Add below code to `RegisterBuildCallback` -

```
var autoActivated = builtContainer
                                      .ComponentRegistry
                                      .Registrations
                                      .Where(registration => IsISomething(registration.Activator.LimitType) && registration.Services.Any(i => i.Description.Equals("AutoActivate")))
                                      .ToList();

                foreach (var iSomethingRegistration in autoActivated)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Auto activated {string.Join("-", iSomethingRegistration.Services)} ");
                }
```

Comment: The question is if there's a way to handle `AutoActivate` components using this approach. The code you've provided removes `AutoActivate`, so I assume the answer is "no"?

Comment: That gets me most of the way there. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @AndyJ .